# Selector drawable in RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-selector, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I have customized a `RadioGroup` to work as a "tab holder". Each "tab" is a `RadioButton`.

I have set `android:button=@null`because I am just using the text and also I have set a selector to the background.

When the `RadioButton` is checked or unchecked the selector works properly, however, when I try to add pressed state it doesn't work.

It seems it only recognizes checked or unchecked states. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using state_selected in your xml selector and change RadioButton selected state from code.